# Some threads calculating correctly, others not

Tags: c, parallel-processing

Simple parallel adder.  You pass it the pointer to the first element in the array, a pointer to the last element in the array, the element # of the first pointer, and the number of elements in this portion of the array being operated on.

```
    double my_func (double *x, double *x_last, int first_pos, int n)
    {
      if (n ==1) {
        return x[first_pos];
      }
      else if (n == 2) {
        return x[first_pos] + x[first_pos+1];
      }
      else {
        double x1,x2;

        x1 = _Cilk_spawn my_func (&x[first_pos], &x[n/2+first_pos-1],first_pos, n/2);
        x2 = my_func (&x[n/2+first_pos],&x[first_pos+n-1],n/2+first_pos, n-n/2);
        _Cilk_sync;

        return x1 + x2;
      }
    }
```

Let's say we start with an array of size 80.  This works perfectly for element #0-19 (the first quarter), then returns a bunch of 0's/garbage for elements #20-39 and all elements after.  Clearly both the x1 and x2 lines are working to some degree, but the function breaks down and I don't know why.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're slicing the array wrong:

```
x1 = my_func (&x[n/2+first_pos],&x[first_pos+n-1],n/2+first_pos, n-n/2);
                    ^                                 ^
            new "base" pointer                first pos in slice?!
```

You can't pass *both* an adjusted pointer to the slice's first element, *and* that element's global index. You end up indexing more than once, so to speak, leading to invalid addresses being dereferenced.

For the case of `n = 80`, the second recursive call will pass `x` pointing at element `&x[80/2+0]`, i.e. `&x[40]`, but it will also set `first_pos` to `40` for that call. Eventually you'll reach down to `n < 3`, and index using accumulated `first_pos`.

Also, the input data should be `const` if it's read-only, for clarity's sake.

Comment: I figured I needed to pass first_pos in order to keep track of where future slices should occur.  So if I want to add x[4:7], so i'll pass (&x[4], &x[7]), but then I have to retain that 4 to calculate the next slice, right?  I guess I don't understand how this leads to invalid addresses.

Comment: Indeed. The same parameter looks wrong here, too: `x2 = my_func (&x[n/2+first_pos],&x[first_pos+n-1],n/2+first_pos, n-n/2);`... Seems to me like this function needs an *assert(first_pos == 0);* to ensure sane input ;)

Comment: "Eventually you'll reach down to n < 3, and index using accumulated first_pos." I don't follow?  When n < 3 the return value is returned and the first_pos is not... what is accumulated?

Comment: @user1956609 In that case, please explain `&x[first_pos]`.

Comment: n contains the number of elements that the function can access, right? Use `assert` from `<assert.h>` to help you: `assert(first_pos < n);` says "I assert that first_pos shall be less than n". If the assertion fails, you'll probably be told when you try to run your program in debug mode.

Comment: Let's say I have n=8.  The initial call will be my_func(&x[0],&x[7],0,8).  Now I want to slice, and the next two calls will be my_func(&x[0],&x[3],0,4) and my_func(&x[4],&x[7],4,4).  Now, if I want to further slice the latter, I need that first_pos = 4 parameter (and the n=4 final parameter) to calculate the next slice, which gives me my_func(&x[4],&x[5],4,2) and my_func(&x[6],&x[7],6,2).  If I don't know that that segment starts at element #4, how would I know where to slice?  If there's an easier way I'm certainly open to it, but this seemed pretty straightforward before I got the error.

Comment: What is the address of x in the initial call? What is the address of x in my_func(&x[4],&x[7],4,4)? What is the address of x in my_func(&x[6],&x[7],6,2)? Is &x[6] equal to &initial_x[6]? Why not?

Comment: Ahhhh.  I think I got it...  So if I pass (&x[first_pos], &x[n/2+first_pos-1]), then in the new function iteration, x[0] is x[first_pos]... so if I put in x[first_pos] that actually gave me x[2*first_pos]?